# What is the probability that a quadrilateral inside a square is convex?

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

Need probability that ABCD is convex if the points have coordinates $(x_1,y_1)(x_2,y_2)(x_3,y_3)(x_4,y_4)$ where $x_i,y_i\in[0,1]$ are uniformly equiprobable.

It would be same as the expected value of the green area but I can't get it...

[image]

I guess Monte Carlo would do the job

Comment: $D$ is sort of missing.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe D is somewhere in the green

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For question in its current form, the probability is $\frac13$ of the expected area of the green. In your figure, $ABCD$ will be a convex quadrilateral only when $D$ falls inside the green area in lower left.

In any event, the answer is $\frac{25}{108}$.

If you pick 4 points uniformly from a square, aside from events of zero probabilities where you get degenerate polygons, there are two possibilities:

- the convex hull of the 4 points is a triangle.
  In this case, there is no way to reorder the points to get a convex quadrilateral.
- the convex hull of the 4 points is a quadrilateral.
  Among the $4! = 24$ possible reordering of the $4$ points, $8$ of them
  give you convex quadrilaterals.

The problem of finding the probability that the convex hull is a quadrilateral
is the [Sylvestor's four-point problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SylvestersFour-PointProblem.html). The probability is known to be $\frac{25}{36}$.

Combine these, the probability you want is
$\frac{8}{24} \times \frac{25}{36} = \frac{25}{108}$.

Comment: Actually I needed the probability that the convex hull is a quadrilateral, so it is $\frac{25}{36}$. Great piece of information you provided here, I didn't know for this Sylverstor's problem. Thanks!

Comment: And you are right, I misstated the question, the way I stated it is matter the order of the points. I was only thinking of picking 4 point that you can make a convex quad. But you provided answer for both forms of the question anyway :)